# EJB transaction rollback causes unwanted database changes / object persistence

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, transactions

I've got a problem with rolling back my EJB transaction in case of an error. Following situation: I've a stateless EJB which tries to persist 3 objects within a new transaction. I'm using Hibernate 5.2 as JPA Provider and Payara 4.1.2.173 as application server.

```
@Stateless
public class MyEJB {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "myUnit")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void persistData() {
        this.log.info("Method start.");
        // valid
        MyObj obj1 = new MyObj();
        obj1.setField1("v1");
        obj1.setField2("v2");
        entityManager.persist(obj1);
        this.log.info("Persisted obj1");

        // valid
        MyObj obj2 = new MyObj();
        obj2.setField1("v1");
        obj2.setField2("v2");
        entityManager.persist(obj2);
        this.log.info("Persisted obj2");

        // failure
        MyObj obj3 = new MyObj();
        obj3.setField1("v1");
        obj3.setField2("FAILURE");
        entityManager.persist(obj3);
        this.log.info("Persisted obj3");

        this.log.info("Method finished.");
    }
}
```

The persistence of obj3 should fail because of an invalid value on field2. While calling this method from outside my ejb (e. g. from another EJB, a message driven bean, via rest, ...) a `PersistenceException` occurs in the logfiles while executing the hibernate insert statements. So obj3 is not persisted in the database. The logfile also says "Transaction marked for rollback". But when I take a look into the database obj1 and obj2 are persisted. So IMHO the rollback is not done or incomplete.
I also tried using the `@Transactional` annotation but no behavior change. I can't use a try-catch neither because while object creation and `persist(obj)` call no exception occurs.
In the `persistence.xml` I set the property `hibernate.connection.autocommit` to `false`.

My persistence.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">
    <persistence-unit name="myUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/name</jta-data-source>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform"/>
            <property name = "hibernate.show_sql" value = "false" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The database connection is done in the pool definition in Payaras' domain.xml:

```
<resources>

    <jdbc-resource pool-name="pool-name" jndi-name="jdbc/name"></jdbc-resource>

    <jdbc-connection-pool match-connections="true" connection-leak-reclaim="true" driver-classname="" statement-leak-reclaim="true" 
                          connection-creation-retry-attempts="3" associate-with-thread="true" validation-table-name="DUAL" 
                          description="" validation-classname="" res-type="javax.sql.XADataSource" max-wait-time-in-millis="120000" 
                          fail-all-connections="true" allow-non-component-callers="true" datasource-classname="oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource" 
                          is-connection-validation-required="true" transaction-isolation-level="read-committed" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="30" 
                          lazy-connection-enlistment="true" connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="7" max-pool-size="45" 
                          connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="1800" statement-leak-timeout-in-seconds="900" steady-pool-size="10" 
                          name="pool-name" statement-timeout-in-seconds="900" sql-trace-listeners="" init-sql="">
      <property name="Password" value="password"></property>
      <property name="User" value="user"></property>
      <property name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/db-identifier"></property>
    </jdbc-connection-pool>
</resources>
```

The stacktrace of my failure is shown in the following paragraph. As you can see 3 insert statements are created. After the `persistData()` code is done, Hibernate tries to execute the statements and at obj3-insert a failure occurs and a rollback is initiated. But obj1 and obj2 are persisted in the database afterwards. I've added some log statements for better understanding.

```
[2018-09-02T17:41:51.111+0200] [Payara 4.1] [INFO] [] [...] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(2)] [timeMillis: 1535903502294] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Method start.]]

[2018-09-02T17:41:51.222+0200] [Payara 4.1] [INFO] [] [...] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(2)] [timeMillis: 1535903502430] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Persisted obj1]]

[2018-09-02T17:41:51.333+0200] [Payara 4.1] [INFO] [] [...] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(2)] [timeMillis: 1535903502431] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Persisted obj2]]

[2018-09-02T17:41:51.444+0200] [Payara 4.1] [INFO] [] [...] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(2)] [timeMillis: 1535903502432] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Persisted obj3]]

[2018-09-02T17:41:51.555+0200] [Payara 4.1] [INFO] [] [...] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(2)] [timeMillis: 1535903502432] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Method finished.]]

[2018-09-02T17:41:51.789+0200] [Payara 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=27 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(1)] [timeMillis: 1535902911789] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Hibernate: insert into ... // obj1

[2018-09-02T17:41:51.929+0200] [Payara 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=27 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(1)] [timeMillis: 1535902911929] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Hibernate: insert into ... // obj2

[2018-09-02T17:41:51.931+0200] [Payara 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=27 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(1)] [timeMillis: 1535902911931] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Hibernate: insert into ... // obj3

[2018-09-02T17:41:51.939+0200] [Payara 4.1] [WARN] [] [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] [tid: _ThreadID=27 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(1)] [timeMillis: 1535902911939] [levelValue: 900] [[
  SQL Error: 12899, SQLState: 72000]]

[2018-09-02T17:41:51.939+0200] [Payara 4.1] [ERROR] [] [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] [tid: _ThreadID=27 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(1)] [timeMillis: 1535902911939] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  ORA-12899: Wert zu groß für Spalte "FIELD2" (aktuell: 7, maximal: 1)
]]

[2018-09-02T17:41:51.941+0200] [Payara 4.1] [INFO] [] [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl] [tid: _ThreadID=27 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(1)] [timeMillis: 1535902911941] [levelValue: 800] [[
  HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements]]

[2018-09-02T17:41:51.946+0200] [Payara 4.1] [ERROR] [] [org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl] [tid: _ThreadID=27 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(1)] [timeMillis: 1535902911946] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement]]]

[2018-09-02T17:41:51.946+0200] [Payara 4.1] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.jta.com.sun.enterprise.transaction] [tid: _ThreadID=27 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(1)] [timeMillis: 1535902911946] [levelValue: 900] [[
  DTX5014: Caught exception in beforeCompletion() callback:
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1434)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3190)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2404)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:467)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion(JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:320)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.synchronization.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.synchronization.RegisteredSynchronization.beforeCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:37)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.commit(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:452)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.commit(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:879)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:721)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:505)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4536)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2023)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1994)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:90)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy406.testImport(Unknown Source)
    at ...
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1606)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:654)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:480)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3001)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3501)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:586)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:460)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1428)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-12899: Wert zu groß für Spalte "FIELD2" (aktuell: 7, maximal: 1)

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1059)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:225)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:53)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:943)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1150)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4798)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4875)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1361)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.PreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(PreparedStatementWrapper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
    ... 81 more
]]
```

Can somebody explain why the valid insert statements are executed and not rolled back and what I can do to achieve a full rollback? The behavior I'd like is to insert all entries into the database within my transaction or no entry at all (in case of any error).

Comment: Please show your persistence.xml file

Comment: I've edit my question and added persistence.xml and excerpt of domain.xml

Comment: Try removing all the properties from the persistence.xml except for `hibernate.show_sql`.

Comment: No change in behaviour. obj1 and obj2 are still persisted

Comment: can you post the Payara log file when you try to persists `obj3`

Comment: Stacktrace would be nice also. Does it show that `PersistenceException` occurs in line `entityManager.persist(obj3);`?

Comment: I've added some logfiles to my code and post a stacktrace. The failure does not occur within my code. Hibernate tries to persist the objects after my code is executed. During my code the statements are just prepared but not checked against database restrictions (in case of obj3.field2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved my problem. The issue was that within my used Payara server-configuration the jdbc-resource was not registered. After adding it to the server configuration within the `domain.xml` everything worked as expected.

```
<resources>
    <jdbc-resource pool-name="pool-name" jndi-name="jdbc/name"></jdbc-resource>
    <jdbc-connection-pool ...> </jdbc-connection-pool>
</resources>
...
<servers>
  <server config-ref="server-config" name="server">
    ...
    <resource-ref ref="jdbc/name"></resource-ref>
  </server>
</servers>
```